# Nvidia Compatibility in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I am using Ubuntu  14.04.1 for sometime. It uses my Intel HD 4000 graphics in my Laptop, but I want it to use y Nvidia GT 740m graphics card to. I have the nouveau driver for Nvidia, but it seems like its not using it.

`lspci -v | grep VGA` yields

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

And also Ubuntu is able to recognize the Nvidia graphics card

```
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 21da
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Capabilities: [900] #19
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

What should I do to use my Nvidia graphics card in Ubuntu. Previously I tried using Bumblebee but it screwed up my laptop. Should I go for the proprietary drivers that Ubuntu's additional driver provides ?

Thank You

Comment: I would encourage people to use `lspci -nnk | grep '\[03' -A2` instead, and yes, go for the proprietary driver please, see [how do I install additional drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me to activate my Nvidia card (I put all the steps even if you have done some already) :

1. Remove all old Nvidia & Nvidia related packages :

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1 bumblebee* nvidia*
   ```
2. Install Nvidia driver :

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
   ```
3. Open `Nvidia X Server Settings`, go in `PRIME Profiles` and select `Nvidia (High Performance Mode)`

---

You can also install `prime-indicator` that will let you quickly switch between your Intel HD 4000 graphics and your Nvidia GT 740m card :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

[image: prime-indicator]

Prime-indicator and screenshot credit to [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html).

Comment: I installed Nvidia X server settings as you said, but it does't have any prime profiles.

Comment: Something weird happened. I locked my account, and went to have my lunch. Came back and my keyboard won't work. So I restarted my laptop, and booted into Ubuntu. A message popped up that "Your system is low on graphics card" I pressed OK and it rendered me into the default tty. Then I uninstalled nvidia-355 and again rebooted my laptop. Now its working fine.

Comment: Why won't ubuntu work with Nvidia ? :-(

Comment: Really? thats weird. Try the updated answer please.